# What do the different status error codes for the CheckValidationResult certificateProblem parameter stand for?

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate

In the [MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.icertificatepolicy.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) of the ICertificatePolicy interface, there is an enum which lists all the possible status error codes that can be returned via the `ValidationCallback`:

```
public enum CertificateProblem : long
{
        CertEXPIRED                   = 0x800B0101,
        CertVALIDITYPERIODNESTING     = 0x800B0102,
        CertROLE                      = 0x800B0103,
        CertPATHLENCONST              = 0x800B0104,
        CertCRITICAL                  = 0x800B0105,
        CertPURPOSE                   = 0x800B0106,
        CertISSUERCHAINING            = 0x800B0107,
        CertMALFORMED                 = 0x800B0108,
        CertUNTRUSTEDROOT             = 0x800B0109,
        CertCHAINING                  = 0x800B010A,
        CertREVOKED                   = 0x800B010C,
        CertUNTRUSTEDTESTROOT         = 0x800B010D,
        CertREVOCATION_FAILURE        = 0x800B010E,
        CertCN_NO_MATCH               = 0x800B010F,
        CertWRONG_USAGE               = 0x800B0110,
        CertUNTRUSTEDCA               = 0x800B0112
}
```

What do these different status codes stand for?  They are not in the SSPI Status Code document that the links reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent a long time trying to figure this out, and was finally able to find a [VMware C# file](http://www.vmware.com/communities/content/developer/samplecode/c/CloneVM.html) containing explanations of the different codes:

**CertEXPIRED**
A required certificate is not within its validity period

**CertVALIDITYPERIODNESTING**
The validity periods of the certification chain do not nest correctly

**CertROLE**
A certificate that can only be used as an end-entity is being used as a CA or visa versa

**CertPATHLENCONST**
A path length constraint in the certification chain has been violated

**CertCRITICAL**
An extension of unknown type that is labeled 'critical' is present in a certificate

**CertPURPOSE**
A certificate is being used for a purpose other than that for which it is permitted

**CertISSUERCHAINING**
A parent of a given certificate in fact did not issue that child certificate

**CertMALFORMED**
A certificate is missing or has an empty value for an important field, such as a subject or issuer name

**CertUNTRUSTEDROOT**
A certification chain processed correctly, but terminated in a root certificate which isn't trusted by the trust provider

**CertCHAINING**
A chain of certs didn't chain as they should in a certain application of chaining

**CertREVOKED**
A certificate was explicitly revoked by its issuer

**CertUNTRUSTEDTESTROOT**
The root certificate is a testing certificate and the policy settings disallow test certificates

**CertREVOCATION_FAILURE**
The revocation process could not continue - the certificate(s) could not be checked

**CertCN_NO_MATCH**
The certificate's CN name does not match the passed value

**CertWRONG_USAGE**
The certificate is not valid for the requested usage

**CertUNTRUSTEDCA**
Untrusted CA